# process.env.PORT and process.env.NODE_ENV are both returning undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to learn MERN and have hit an issue straight away

```
 App.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server started on PORT: ${process.env.PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode.`)
})
```

returns "Server started on PORT: undefined in undefined mode."

Here is structure

backend:

```
config:

  config.ev
```

App.js

server.js

App.js>
`const express = require('express); const App = express(); module.exports = App`

server.js> `const App = require('./App');

const dotenv = require('dotenv')

// Config set up

dotenv.config({ path: 'backend\config\config.env'})

App.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server started on PORT: ${process.env.PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode.`)
})`

config.env `PORT = 4000 NODE_ENV = DEVELOPMENT`

Comment: you can try replacing `backend\config\config.env` with `${__dirname}backend\config\config.env`.

Comment: No, still the same output

Answer (score 0):

to require dotenv, use this instead of what you have currently

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
```

i also noticed some typos in your question like the missing quotation mark when you required express but i assume this was a typo from writing it on here and not in your actual code.

and you can find more info on dotenv [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv?activeTab=readme)

Comment: No still getting the same result with 
        const App = require('./App');
        const dotenv = require('dotenv');
        dotenv.config({ path: 'backend\config\config.env'})

Comment: same with `require('dotenv').config({ path: 'backend\config\config.env'})` without first assigning it to a variable

Comment: oh i see now. if you haven't solved it already, try `require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'backend/config/config.env') })`. because i don't fully understand the file structure with how it's presented, i might be wrong with the actual param i passed in. so you can have a play with [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathresolvepaths) and print it in log to see whether you get your expected directory.